# Auto submit form - Looping issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following form setup:

```
<body>

<form id="main" name='main' action='/IMC Tools/IMC_Directory_Tool/staff/index.php' method='post' <?php if ( isset($_form_params_) ) echo $_form_params_; ?>>
<?php echo $hm->Zb('@page:state'); ?>


<table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1'>
    <tr>
        <td class='column_caption' style='width:150px;'>
          <?php echo $hm->Zb('rs:def:username_login', ZB_ATTR, array( "value" => "admin" )); ?>
          <?php echo $hm->Zb('rs:def:password_login', ZB_ATTR, array( "value" => "password" )); ?>
          <input type="submit" title="ENTER" value="ENTER" id="auto_enter" name="_sc=_this/auth&amp;">
        </td>
    </tr>   
</table>

</form>

</body>
```

I tried using the following script but the pages just keeps going on a infinite loop on the same page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"><!--
document.getElementById ('main').submit ()
//--></script>
```

Tried other similar examples online but they are all giving me the same problem where the page keeps looping and never authenticates. Any help here would be great been scratching my head for several hours on this.

UPDATE possible javascript conflict?:

```
function CallSubmit( action, param, method )
{
    param = param || "";
    method = method || "POST";

    var f = document.forms["main"];
    f["action"] = action;
    f["method"] = method;

    //--- [BEGIN] Brwoser Safari
    if ( navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1  )
    {
        var obj = event.srcElement;
        if ( obj.name.length > 0 )
        {
            f["action"] += "?" + obj.name;
        }
    }
    //--- [END] Brwoser Safari

    f.submit();

    return false;
}
```

Comment: you're just submitting your form unconditionally. What exactly is it that you're trying to achieve ? Also your code should not go into infinite loop unless your `index.php` action is returning same html and script that you just posted

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the form might be submitting to the page where it lives. You might want to either:

1. Have a separate page to handle the submission, or
2. Check if you're receiving the form data (should be in the $_POST array) and then making sure you're not auto submitting the form anymore, so you break the infinite loop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well at the moment if I remove the script and hit sumbit it works fine. This is PHP application I am using so alot of the actual coding is scattered in various included files. Would there be an easy way to have a script click the submit button automatically since I know that works?

Comment: if you just want to do this on page load, you can do this `<script>
  document.addEventListener('load', function(){
     document.getElementById('main').submit();
 }, false);
</script>`

Comment: This script dosent seem to be working. Nothing happens when I refresh my page. I tried putting this script within the form, in the header, in the body and nothing happens.

Comment: I modified ti to `code`<script> window.addEventListener('load', function(){ document.getElementById('main').submit(); }, false); </script>`code` and im now getting a blank page now so were making progress.

Comment: ya my bad the outer one should be `window.addEventListener`, did you see if it is sending all the request parameters as expected in your Network tab ?

Comment: Yeah when I try to look at the Network details in Firebug it still seems to be looping my page. So at the moment with that code it gives me a white page and if I wait 30 seconds the login page shows up again and just continues lopping.

Comment: Just noticed that the application had a javascript handling post requests and im wondering if this was maybe conflicting with our script somehow. I update my original post to see if this would make sense to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so i found an alternate solution by using Jquery.

```
<script>
$('form').find('input[type="submit"]').trigger('click');
</script>
```